# Swift CoreImage Retaining Memory

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, reactive-cocoa, core-video

I'm using ReactiveCocoa and CoreImage/Video to process videos, CoreImage to transform and filter each `CMSampleBuffer` from the video and ReactiveCocoa to process the buffers in sequence.

My filtering function is fairly simple; all I'm doing is detecting if there's a face in the given image, and cropping the image to the face bounds.

```
static func process(input: CIImage) -> SignalProducer<CIImage?, Types.Error> {
    return SignalProducer { observer, disposable in

            let context = CIContext()

            let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: context, options: nil)

            guard let firstFeature = detector.featuresInImage(input, options: [CIDetectorImageOrientation: NSNumber(integer: 6)]).first else {
                observer.sendNext(nil)
                observer.sendCompleted()
                return
            }

            let cropFilter = CIFilter(name: "CICrop")
            let cropRect: CIVector = CIVector(CGRect: firstFeature.bounds)

            cropFilter?.setValue(input, forKey: "inputImage")
            cropFilter?.setValue(cropRect, forKey: "inputRectangle")

            guard let output = cropFilter?.outputImage else {
                observer.sendNext(nil)
                observer.sendCompleted()
                return
            }

            observer.sendNext(output)
            observer.sendCompleted()

            disposable.addDisposable {
                cropFilter?.setValue(nil, forKey: "inputImage")
            }
        }

}
```

However, somewhere in this function memory is being unintentionally retained. If I wrap the inner SignalProducer block in an `autoreleasepool` statement, everything works fine and my memory usage never gets above 50 MB. But If I don't wrap my filtering code in that, the memory jumps from 30MB to 200MB then the app crashes.

What's being retained and which line is causing it?

EDIT:

I discovered that shortly there after it was this line:

```
guard let firstFeature = detector.featuresInImage(input, options: [CIDetectorImageOrientation: NSNumber(integer: 6)]).first else {
    observer.sendNext(nil)
    observer.sendCompleted()
    return
}
```

Although as to why it's this line, I have no clue. Could this perhaps be a bug in CoreImage itself?